# Wait for a method to complete before executing the next in C#

Tags: c#

I was just wondering if there was a way to make a method wait until the previous method called completed execution without using threads. For exmaple, if there are two method calls,

```
{

   A();

   B();

}
```

I want B() to start running only when A has completed. Is there a way to do this without using threads, in c#?

Comment: This is the default behavior without using threads...

Comment: I don't get the question. If you execute this sequentially, then `B` definitely cannot start until `A` returns.

Comment: Ia `A()` some kind of async call? Post your actual code.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506964/wait-for-winform-usercontrol-to-load

Comment: +1, because there is nothing wrong with this question, even if the answer might seem obvious to most programmers.

Comment: Yes. It is a duplicate. The reason why asked the question was because A() and B() are in a sequence and A() takes a long time to complete and B() has already completed by then. I know it might not make sense but thats whats happening in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not spinning off separate threads that will happen by default.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer

Answer (score 3):

Without using threads (as long as the calls are synchronous, which is the default) this is the default behavior.

For example:

```
Class Foo
{
    var returnVal = A();
    returnVal = B();
    Console.WriteLine(returnVal.ToString());
}
```

B() will only run after A() anyway, and the .ToString() will print out the string representation of returnVal after B() has completed.

To make it do anything else, in fact, you would have to use threads and/or asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 2):

That *is* exactly what happens, unless `A()` starts a new thread.

Comment: even if A starts a new thread, still B will get executed only after A returns

Comment: @DavidePiras This wasn't the OP's question, however: he wants `A` to *complete*, not simply *return* before `B` starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute two methods sequentially, and neither of them are called asynchronously, the first method will block execution of the second method until the first method returns.

A(); B(); will actually call them sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

It is the default for statements to execute sequentially. Method calls make no difference.

This is even true, if a user clicks on a button while a method is running. In this case, the button click handler (like MyButton_Click) will wait for execution until the other method terminates its execution. This happens, because both methods are executed on the same thread, the so-called UI-thread.

Answer (score 0):

it will automatically. You could also do this:

Example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
int i = 0;
i =  A();
i =  B();
System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}

public int A(){
  return 1;
}
public int B(){
  return 2;
}
```

Output:
2